# how do i use MySql ENUM type? (and is it right for a news feed)

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating a table called `news_feed`, this will log all the actions a user performs.

Lets say I want to store

> user1234 deleted article412 at midday

I then need a table like so

```
timestamp | user_id | subject_type | subject_id | method
```

.

there would be 5 potential methods to log,

```
methods = add/edit/delete/update/report
```

and lets say 2 possible subject_type

```
subjects = article/comment
```

I know i could make my own key where 0=add, 1=delete etc etc but this would make my queries cumbersome to use/write as i'd need to keep consulting the key. Is there a MySql type which can read lots of identially values quickly? is this `ENUM`? how do i use it?!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `ENUM` type for this.

```
CREATE TABLE news_feed (
    ...
    methods ENUM('add', 'edit', 'delete', 'update', 'report'),
    subjects ENUM('article', 'comment')
);
```

Then just use at as you would any other field, e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM news_feed WHERE methods='add';
```

The [documentation for the ENUM type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html) has much more info.

Comment: is there an easy way to do this with phpmyadmin?

Comment: got it, put the potential values in the (length/values) col

Comment: When creating a table in phpmyadmin, just select ENUM from the "Type" dropdown, and then in the "Length/Value" box put the values in single quotes separated by commas. e.g. 'add','edit'  etc.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you take a look at the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html)? It's explained quite well there.